# Devise - User signed out not in after confirmation

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise, devise-confirmable

I'm following the instructions in this Devise wiki article to customize Devise confirmation in my Rails 3.2.x app.

https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/wiki/How%20To:%20Email-only%20sign-up

It's mostly working. After the user signs up, they are signed in as expected. However, when the confirmation link is clicked in the provided email, and the password is entered, the user is redirected to the home page and signed OUT rather than the authentication being persisted.

Any ideas?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Please see [stackoverflow link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18655334/avoid-sign-in-after-confirmation-link-click-using-devise-gem) for some info regarding your question.

Another idea is to set the following settings in your devise.rb:

```
config.allow_unconfirmed_access_for = 2.days
```

This will keep the user signed in right after the sign-up precess (and before confirmation).