# Automatically sign in after confirm with devise

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, devise, devise-confirmable

I am using devise confirmable.  I have some custom things that i need to override from devise's confirm! method, so in my user model i have the following method that overrides it:

```
def confirm!
  super
  gb = Gibbon::API.new(ENV['MAILCHIMP_API_KEY'])
  gb.lists.subscribe({:id => ENV['MAILCHIMP_ID'], :email => {:email => self.email }})
end
```

This works perfectly.  Now I am trying to have it so the user is automatically signed in after confirming, but cannot figure out how.  I know that this is considered a security flaw, but I have weighed the risks and it is worth it for user experience in my site.  I do not want to do anything with the routes file because this method is already working, so i should be able to do it from here.  I have tried putting the following into my configuration file:

```
config.allow_insecure_sign_in_after_confirmation = true
```

but it does not sign the user in.

I've looked at the stack overflow page at [Avoid sign-in after confirmation link click using devise gem?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18655334/avoid-sign-in-after-confirmation-link-click-using-devise-gem) and it does not help so please don't mark this as a duplicate.

Thanks everyone.

Comment: Are you sure you read the second answer there?  It seems to have a solution that I would think works for you: http://stackoverflow.com/a/20961042/897414

Comment: Yes, I read it, but that would involve changing the entire new confirm! method I created which already works.  I want to somehow call sign_in from the method i wrote above.

Comment: Any ideas - i can't figure this out?

Comment: You can't sign a user in from the model, it has to be in the controller which has access to the request and session cookies.

Comment: As Brian implied, the solution suggested in the other question's 2nd answer doesn't involve any changes to your overridden `confirm!` (unless I'm missing something a bit subtle); instead it subclasses the `Devise::ConfirmationsController` and overrides `show`.

Comment: oh, i see.  Bryan, you're right, the controller method works.  I just did not understand without Tim's explanation.

Answer (score 28):

You would change routes.rb and controllers/users/confirmations_controller.rb (maybe default path)

routes.rb to mapping users/confrimations_controller

```
devise_for :users, controllers: {confirmations: 'users/confirmations'}
```

confirmations_controller to automatically sign in and redirect to

```
def after_confirmation_path_for(resource_name, resource)
  sign_in(resource)
  any_path # redirect_to is not necessary
end
```

Comment: sign_in(resource) must be in show method of confirmations_controller, method  after_confirmation_path_for must contain only the path!

Answer (score 14):

Generate the controller:

```
rails generate devise:controllers users -c=confirmations
```

Amend routes:

```
devise_for :users, controllers: {confirmations: 'users/confirmations'}
```

Then overwrite the `show` method:

```
  # app/controllers/users/confirmations_controller.rb
  def show
    super do
      sign_in(resource) if resource.errors.empty?
    end
  end

  def after_confirmation_path_for(resource_name, resource)
    after_sign_in_path_for(resource)
  end
```

Comment: This was exactly what I am looking for, although  `after_confirmation_path_for` was not required for me.

Comment: Overwrite the `after_confirmation_path_for` method is not needed in this case because when you call the `sign_in` (or `sign_out`) method, the `SessionsController` is in charge of the redirections.